# PHP - How to check if process is running with multiple parameters

Tags: php

I know how to check if one instance of process is running but how do I check a particular process running with different parameters for example

```
/usr/local/bin/foo --config /home/config1.txt
/usr/local/bin/foo --config /home/config2.txt
```

Following code checks only process name, how do I check if a process is running with a particular parameter?

```
function is_process_running ($process_name) {
    $result = array();
    exec("/sbin/pidof {$process_name}", $result);
    if(is_array($result) && isset($result[0]) && $result[0] >= 1) {
        return true; 
    }
    return false;
}

 is_process_running('/usr/local/bin/foo --config /home/config1.txt') returns true
 is_process_running('/usr/local/bin/foo --config /home/config3.txt') returns false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function is_process_running ($process_name) {
    $result = array();
    exec("ps -Af | grep {$process_name}", $result);

    // A loop that checks for your result and also checks 
    // that the result isn't the grep command called

    // ps -ax | grep firefox asdfasd
    // returns grep --color=auto firefox asdfasd

    return false;
}
```

Give it a try.  The flag 'f' modifies the output so includes the full call.

Comment: Thanks, how can I remove following information `PROCESS_OWNER  8426     1  0 Feb08 ?        09:43:42` from output

Comment: I would just try a regular expression with the process name and then .* since it is at the end of the string.

Answer (score -1):

Try this bash command to get more details about the processes:

```
ps ax | grep YourProcesName
```

I know that at least java processes would should its Paramerers

Comment: this cannot be an answer..this is just a comment.

Comment: praveen: define answer- if u expect something nthat you can simply copy/paste you right- on the contrary if it is something that gives you all you need to carry  on - i completly disagree

Comment: so what you mean is what you wrote is an answer?? in stackoverflow when you answer it, it is tested and an *ACTUAL ANSWER* to the question. You could just ask this in comment and if it had worked you would then post it as answer. No harm in that. But **this** is definitely not a way to answer a question on stackoverflow.

Comment: still disagree: be aware that answer have context which has a code snippet already. if u expect something that you can simply copy/paste you right - it is not an answer - but on the contrary it is something that gives you all you need to carry on therefore disagree with you completly...giving copy/past type answers is not very helpful imho in long term- unless you enjoy doing copy/past work till the end of your life;)... btw: have slightly reworded the content so it doesn't use questin tag form sentence.